What does "Blow this" mean from the move "The Secret Dare to Dream"?
I screen recorded the portion of the movie to help you understand the context.
I have 2 questions in here.

Does "blow this" means to cancel the engagement?  I could not find any suitable meaning of blow for this?

Is there any name for the elderly woman doing toward the engagement ring?  If there is, what does her action signify? What kind of feelings is she showing by doing that?


The following is the script excerpt.

Older: Let me see. Oh!
Younger: Looks the same as it did last night.
Older: You are a very lucky girl.
Younger: Aren't I just?
Older: Not many men would be willing to take on somebody with your baggage.
Younger: That's an awful thing to say.
Older: Why? It's true. I mean, three kids, a mountain of debt.
Younger: It's not a mountain.
Older: Well, it's not a molehill either.
Younger: You make me sound like some sort of charity case.
Older: I just don't want you to...Oh, forget it.
Younger: No. What?
Older: Blow this.
Younger: I have been engaged a whole twelve hours and already... Aren't you tired of living under a cloud?
Older: Nobody ever said that life was easy.
Younger: I don't want it to be easy. But I do want it to be worth it.


blow is a euphemism for blast, as in damn and blast [this tiresome conversation]

...I think Blow this for a game of soldiers only occurs in British English, but blow there is actually more likely to be sod or f@ck.

Your "script" seems to be the subtitles.  That makes it very hard for us to know who is speaking.  Please edit to add the name of each speaker before they words they speak E.g  "Old woman: Let me see,  Oh // Young woman: Looks the same ..."

@FumbleFingers  I don't think this usage is an expletive-substitute. As Lambie says, it means "mess up".

@JavaLatte: You're quite right. I originally only read what looked like a standalone utterance in the transcript, and assumed the obvious meaning for just that context. But having just watched / listened to it (and realized it continues preceding I just don't want you to...) there's no question about it.

I just don't want you to -Oh, forget it. Younger: No. What? Older: Blow this.
Expression without the division:
I just don't want you to blow this. Presented in two bits.
To blow something is to screw it up or mess it up.
We often use it as a warning: Don't blow it or this.

Wiktionary has blow, v., 17 (transitive): To fail at something; to mess up; to make a mistake.

Thank you Lambie very much for the explanation. Everything falls into place after you connect the 2 phrases.  I thought "blow this" independent, not connected to previous sentence.  The older woman, mother-in-law of the younger woman whose husband died from the plane crash, wants her daughter-in-law to marry the restaurant owner who gave the younger woman the ring in the previous night gathering.  Thank you.

@user1026669 Yes, that's right. :)

It's not  very clear from the script, but on the video I see that actually the older woman says  "I just don't want you to ... blow this"
It seems to be related to the idiom "blow it all", meaning to lose or spend all one's money recklessly).  The old woman means "I don't want you to lose the things that you have (as a result of a reckless marriage?).
It's not clear exactly what the older woman's motives are. The "biting" gesture is not familiar to me. She is alternately enthusiastic, then rude.  She seems to be trying to "gaslight" the younger woman.

Thank you James K very much for the comment.  I thought there was some kind of word for her biting gesture.  I though it could be a part of culture,  For sure, the old lady is trying to influence the younger woman.  Thank you.

Like @Lambie said, "blow [it]" means to make a mistake—generally to the point of failing at whatever it is you were trying to do. Wiktionary:

blow, v., 17 (transitive, informal, idiomatic): To fail at something; to mess up; to make a mistake.
Good luck, and don’t blow it!

"Blow it" is often used where there is a clear "win condition" and a clear "lose condition," like in a sports game or in a political race. If it looks like you might win, but then you make a big mistake and instead you lose, we say you "blew it."
The older woman is saying that she does not want the younger woman to mess up so badly that her fiancé cancels the engagement. (She is in fact being rude.)
Before she says this, the older woman appears to be miming the act of taking a bite of the younger woman's engagement ring. This action is often used to indicate that we find something, often some person, cute or endearing ("You're so cute, I could just gobble you up!"). I don't think this is exactly what the older woman means but it's something along those lines—she is indicating that she is impressed with the engagement ring and what it represents.

Thank you randomhead for the comment.  I knew the meaning of "I blew it", but because the "blow this" is seemingly by itself, I thought it means something else.  I could not connect it to previous sentence. I think your description of the biting action is close to what older woman wants to express.  Thank you for the example word 'gobble up'.
